# Calling a method twice with different values Unit testing using MOQ

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, moq

I want to test a construct which calls a method within it twice to get two different values

```
public class  stubhandler
{

public stubhandler()
{

string codetext = model.getValueByCode(int a,string b); // 1,"High"    result Canada
string datatext = model.getValueByCode(int a,string b); // 10, "Slow"   result Motion

}

}
```

To test the above i use a unit test class

```
[TestMethod]
public void StubHandlerConstructor_Test()
{
Mock<Model> objMock = new Mock<>(Model);
objMock.Setup(m => m.getValueByCode(It.IsAny<int>,It.IsAny<string>)).Returns("Canada");

objMock.Setup(m => m.getValueByCode(It.IsAny<int>,It.IsAny<string>)).Returns("Motion");

stubhandler  classstubhandler = new stubhandler();

}
```

The above method pass but codetext and datatext contains same value Motion
i want them to set to

```
codetext = Canada
datatext = Motion
```

How can i achieve this?

I have tried `objMock.VerifyAll()` which fails the test ??

Comment: It may not be the best way to do it, but why not replace the It.IsAny<int> with specific values that match Canada or Motion specifically?. It feels like a rather clumsy solution though.

Comment: It is the return value that matters not the parameters those are dummy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If using MOQ 4 one can use SetupSequence, else it can be done using a lambda

Using SetupSequence is pretty self explanatory.

Using the lambdas is not too messy.  The important point to not it that the return value is set **at the time that the setup is declared**.  If one just used

```
mockFoo.Setup(mk => mk.Bar()).Returns(pieces[pieceIdx++]);
```

the setup would always return pieces[0].  By using the lambda, the evaluation is deferred until Bar() is invoked.

```
public interface IFoo {
    string Bar();
}

public class Snafu {

    private IFoo _foo;
    public Snafu(IFoo foo) {
        _foo = foo;
    }

    public string GetGreeting() {
        return string.Format("{0} {1}",
                             _foo.Bar(),
                             _foo.Bar());
    }

}

[TestMethod]
public void UsingSequences() {

    var mockFoo = new Mock<IFoo>();
    mockFoo.SetupSequence(mk => mk.Bar()).Returns("Hello").Returns("World");

    var snafu = new Snafu(mockFoo.Object);

    Assert.AreEqual("Hello World", snafu.GetGreeting());

}

[TestMethod]
public void NotUsingSequences() {

    var pieces = new[] {
            "Hello",
            "World"
    };
    var pieceIdx = 0;

    var mockFoo = new Mock<IFoo>();
    mockFoo.Setup(mk => mk.Bar()).Returns(()=>pieces[pieceIdx++]);

    var snafu = new Snafu(mockFoo.Object);

    Assert.AreEqual("Hello World", snafu.GetGreeting());

}
```

Comment: i had to use the 2nd way due the moq version, fab works like a charm. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

[Moq documentation](http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart) says you *can simulate* something like successive returns with `Callback` method:

```
var values = new [] { "Canada", "Motion" };
int callNumber = 0;

mock.Setup(m => m.getValueByCode(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns((i,s) => values[callNumber])
    .Callback(() => callNumber++);
```

This will do the trick, but it's not the most elegant solution. [Matt Hamilton proposes](http://madprops.org/blog/moq-triqs-successive-expectations/) much better one in his blog post, with clever use of queue:

```
var values = new Queue<string> { "Canada", "Motion" };

mock.Setup(m => m.getValueByCode(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns(() => values.Dequeue());
```

Calling `mock.Object.getValueByCode` twice, will produce `"Canada"` and `"Motion"` strings respectively.

Comment: its funny tired both the above method the first one get "canada" for both and the second using queues gets Urgent. Didn't work for me?

Comment: @Gauls: thanks, there's been error with first solution - `Returns` has to be specified lazily via lambda (fixed now). No clue what's wrong with `Queue` one, works on my box.